# How to enable logging for third party containers in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

The similar as Docker using this as below to configure logging in compose file for third party (mariadb, opentsdb ...) to show logs on Kibana.

```
logging:
            driver: fluentd
            options:
                fluentd-address: "0.0.0.0:24224"
                tag: "docker.{{.ID}}"
```

I want to ask that how to configure for Kubernetes?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can use `fluentd` to collect logs and push them to 3rd party log storage (**StackDriver** or **ElasticSearch**). To ensure that `fluentd` is running on every cluster node we can use **DaemonSet** object.

> As an example let’s see a part of the file content:
>
> ```
> apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
> kind: DaemonSet
> metadata:
>   name: fluentd
>   namespace: kube-system
>   ...
> spec:
>     ...
>     spec:
>       containers:
>       - name: fluentd
>         image: quay.io/fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset
>         env:
>           - name:  FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
>             value: "elasticsearch-logging"
>           - name:  FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
>             value: "9200"
>         ...
> ```

[This article](https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/kubernetes-fluentd) describes most important steps to get everything set up.

> #### Get Fluentd DaemonSet sources
>
> We have created a Fluentd DaemonSet that have the proper rules and container image ready to get started:
>
> ```
> https://github.com/fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset
> ```
>
> Please grab a copy of the repository from the command line using GIT:
>
> ```
> $ git clone https://github.com/fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset
> ```